# php Split multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array (

    [0] => Array (
        [nombre] => Juan Mandrola
        [id] => 5
        [fecha_egreso] => 15/10/2014
        [hora_egreso] => 15:00
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [nombre] => Pedro Martinez
        [id] => 5
        [fecha_egreso] => 17/10/2014
        [hora_egreso] => 15:00
    )

)
```

I need to separate the first array into 2 arrays, changing the element "nombre" for "mecanico" and the other elements in another array named "tarea".

```
Array (

    [0] => Array (
        [mecanico] => Juan Mandrola
        [tarea] => Array (
                [id] => 1
                [fecha_egreso] => 15/10/2014
                [hora_egreso] => 15:00
            )

    )

    [1] => Array (
        [mecanico] => Pedro Martinez
        [tarea] => Array (
                [id] => 5
                [fecha_egreso] => 17/10/2014
                [hora_egreso] => 15:00
            )

    )
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm seeing alot of *I want/I need* what have you tried?

Comment: Walk the array and modify it as you need

Comment: I bet u haven't tried a line for that

Comment: Daryl Gill yes, I tried but did not speak very good English for that reason do not place my code and explain it to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quick and dirty solution would be to create a new array and assign the values as you need. While it's not the best way to do things, here's the pseudocode:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($myOldArray); $i++) {
  $myNewArray[$i]['mecanico']    = $myOldArray[$i]['nombre'];
  $myNewArray[$i]['tarea']['id'] = $myOldArray[$i]['id'];
  $myNewArray[$i]['tarea']['fecha_egreso'] = $myOldArray[$i]['fecha_egreso'];
  $myNewArray[$i]['tarea']['hora_egreso']  = $myOldArray[$i]['hora_egreso'];
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, but please keep in mind that you're duplicating the amount of data resources your program uses for each use of this code snippet. If the amount of data you pass through this snippet is very large, this approach could have a noticeable performance impact. **Usually**, you will be fine with the quick and dirty method, but it's good to understand the consequences going in.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
 $newArray[]['tarea'] = array('id'=>$val['id'], 'fecha_egreso'=>$val['fecha_egreso'], 'hora_egreso'=>$val['egreso']);
 $newArray[]['mecanico'] = $val['nombre'];
}
```